# How to create a python dictionary for a weight calculator module

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

trying to make a python dictionary that passes in a list of weight level names and counts for two occasions: one if everything is normal, one to custom define. I want to make a function/class variable that can be used to determine whether to do a custom count or straight count and then for generalizing after that the total level count should be based on the function/class variable and then a for loop that takes in level name and level count variable.

The goal is to create a program that creates a list of weights based on an input of a list of level names. How would I create a for loop after this code to determine if I will be doing a custom count or straight count? Also how can I append to custom_level_dict with a loop? The last step would be setting a user defined number of levels, which I am not sure how to do either.

```
    total_level =[]
    key = ["level_mame"]
    value = ["level_count"]
    custom_level_dict= {[key]:[value]}

    if key, value not in custom_level_dict:
        total_level += (self.df[value] == self.df[key].str.lower().nunique())
        
    else:
        self.df.loc[(self.df['level_name'] == key),'level_count'] == value
        total_level += custom_level_dict.values()
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question. Be specific and point out how your solution is deficient. What are you having trouble with? Focus on one problem you are having. Take the [tour] and read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or a tutorial.

Comment: ok just updated my question

Answer (score 0):

As lists aren't hashable elements, your `custom_level_dict` creation was incorrect because you were passing a list as a key element. It can be solved by accessing the string value of both lists `key` and `value` as follows:

```
key = ["level_mame"]
value = ["level_count"]
custom_level_dict= {key[0]:value[0]}
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I create the for loop for normal/custom defining counts?

Comment: @keralivington Please add more detail in your question and clarify your input and output, in addition to the goal of your code.

Comment: okay just added!